# Using `rerun` to concatenate

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr

The `rerun` is faster than `for`. I'd like to know if is possible to concatenate an expression using `rerun`. For example, in first iteration I'd like to obtain `print((x[1 + 1] + y[1])/y[1])`. In second iteration I'd like to obtain `print((x[2 + 1] + y[2])/y[2])`. The code above present the MWE:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 11:15
for(i in 1:5){
  if(i < 5){
    print((x[i + 1] + y[i])/y[i])
  }
  else{
    print(1.5)
  }  
}
```

I agree that `rerun` is used with an objective different from `for`, but  is it possible to adapt?

Comment: I added `x` and `y`.

Comment: @WagnerJorge Try explaining more clearly. What does this mean *I'd like to know if concatenate expression using `rerun`* if what?

Comment: I guess your example may be simple enough that it can be vectorized without a loop i.e. `i <- 5; v1 <- (x[seq_len(i)+1] + y[seq_len(i)])/y[seq_len(i)]; ifelse(is.na(v1), 1.5, v1)#[1] 1.181818 1.250000 1.307692 1.357143 1.500000`

Comment: Yes, it is a MWE.